How to Merge HTML Table Cells in Angular?
I have a dynamic HTML table in my Angular 15 application. I want to merge all adjacent cells with the same value, both vertically and horizontally, irrespective of the column or row. For example, if my table has cells like this:
string string string 
string string string    =>    string
string string string


How can I achieve this in Angular with TypeScript?
Here is a basic structure of my dynamic table:
<!-- HTML File -->
<div class="table-wrapper">
    <table class="fl-table" aria-describedby="table-description">
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let row of tableData">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let columnName of columnNames">
            <td>{{ row[columnName] }}</td>
        </ng-container>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

I have tried this approach, but it is not working as expected.
My Approch
// .ts file
columnNames: any[] = [];
tableData: any[] = [];

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.mergeCells();
}

getColumnNames(data: any) {
  if (data.length > 0) {
    this.columnNames = Object.keys(data[0]);
  }
}
mergeCells(): void {
const tableElement: HTMLTableElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('table');

let headerCells: HTMLTableCellElement[] = [];

for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < tableElement.rows.length; rowIndex++) {
    const row = tableElement.rows[rowIndex];

    for (let colIndex = 0; colIndex < row.cells.length; colIndex++) {
    const cell = row.cells[colIndex];

    if (cell.innerText.trim() === '') {
        continue;
    }

    if (headerCells[colIndex] === undefined || cell.innerText !== headerCells[colIndex].innerText) {
        headerCells[colIndex] = cell;
    } else {
        headerCells[colIndex].rowSpan++;
        cell.remove();
    }
    }
}
}

Table Data for reference:
columnNames: any[] = [];
  // tableData: any[] = [];
  tableData: any[] = [
    {
      "0": "",
      "1": "",
      "2": "key1",
      "3": "key1",
      "4": "key2",
      "5": "key2",
      "6": "value5",
      "7": "value5",
    },
    {
      "0": "",
      "1": "",
      "2": "key1",
      "3": "key1",
      "4": "key2",
      "5": "key2",
      "6": "value5",
      "7": "value5",
    },
    {
      "0": "",
      "1": "",
      "2": "Count",
      "3": "Amount",
      "4": "Count",
      "5": "Amount",
      "6": "Count",
      "7": "Amount",
    },
    {
      "0": "Loaded Data",
      "1": "All",
      "2": 245205,
      "3": "495693992.68",
      "4": 238112,
      "5": "475560898.63",
      "6": 247642,
      "7": "53858508052.00",
    },
    {
      "0": "Status",
      "1": "value1",
      "2": 233398,
      "3": "464734379.76",
      "4": 233398,
      "5": "464734379.76",
      "6": 233398,
      "7": "46473437976.00",
    },
    {
      "0": "Status",
      "1": "value2",
      "2": 11807,
      "3": "30959612.92",
      "4": 4714,
      "5": "10826518.87",
      "6": 14244,
      "7": "7385070076.00",
    },
    {
      "0": "key2",
      "1": "value1",
      "2": 237591,
      "3": "473886210.33",
      "4": "",
      "5": "",
      "6": 233900,
      "7": "46634667766.00",
    },
    {
      "0": "key2",
      "1": "value2",
      "2": 7614,
      "3": "21807782.35",
      "4": "",
      "5": "",
      "6": 13742,
      "7": "7223840286.00",
    },
    {
      "0": "key2",
      "1": "value3",
      "2": 7084,
      "3": "20074807.55",
      "4": "",
      "5": "",
      "6": 13584,
      "7": "7173509166.00",
    },
    {
      "0": "key2",
      "1": "value4",
      "2": 530,
      "3": "1732974.80",
      "4": "",
      "5": "",
      "6": 158,
      "7": "50331120.00",
    },
    {
      "0": "value5",
      "1": "value1",
      "2": 233398,
      "3": "464734379.76",
      "4": 233900,
      "5": "466346677.66",
      "6": "",
      "7": "",
    },
    {
      "0": "value5",
      "1": "value2",
      "2": 11807,
      "3": "30959612.92",
      "4": 4212,
      "5": "9214220.97",
      "6": "",
      "7": "",
    },
    {
      "0": "value5",
      "1": "value3",
      "2": 3695,
      "3": "7687836.58",
      "4": 3565,
      "5": "7224948.37",
      "6": "",
      "7": "",
    },
    {
      "0": "value5",
      "1": "value4",
      "2": 8112,
      "3": "23271776.34",
      "4": 647,
      "5": "1989272.60",
      "6": "",
      "7": "",
    },
    {
      "0": "key1",
      "1": "value1",
      "2": "",
      "3": "",
      "4": 237591,
      "5": "473886210.33",
      "6": 233398,
      "7": "46473437976.00",
    },
    {
      "0": "key1",
      "1": "value2",
      "2": "",
      "3": "",
      "4": 521,
      "5": "1674688.30",
      "6": 14244,
      "7": "7385070076.00",
    },
    {
      "0": "key1",
      "1": "value3",
      "2": "",
      "3": "",
      "4": 1,
      "5": "2000.00",
      "6": 6151,
      "7": "4983865494.00",
    },
    {
      "0": "key1",
      "1": "value4",
      "2": "",
      "3": "",
      "4": 520,
      "5": "1672688.30",
      "6": 8093,
      "7": "2401204582.00",
    },
  ]



I don't think you can - when you use Angular you necessarily cede control over the raw HTML/DOM to Angular, so doing things like colspans and rowspans is likely going to break things. I note that most non-trivial data-tables and "data-grids" in Angular (and React) aren't based on <table> and instead use loads of nested <div> elements with display: grid; because it's more powerful/flexible.

If you want to merge both adjacent cells and columns with same value how would that work for an example like this.

you might structure your data with indexes defining row# and column#.  Then re-map the data accordingly.   So a MyDataTable contains Row[], Row contains index: number, and cells: Cell[].  Cell contains columnindex: number, value: string.  Using that you can assign ids to read when handling whatever event triggers this and then remap MyDataTable.

remap meaning take all the values from the rowindex-cellindex's and add then to destination rowindex-cellindex.  Then clear the values from the selected rowindex-cellindex's.
